# TypeORM innerJoin table and filter by joined table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, typeorm

This is my actual query:

```
const query = this.doctorsRepository.createQueryBuilder('doctor')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('doctor.services', 'services')

await query.getMany();
```

This is the result:

```
[
    {
      "id": 3,
      "created_at": "2021-09-09T14:11:09.779Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-09T14:11:09.779Z",
      "name": "Test Doctor Name",
      "bio": "Test Doctor Bio",
      "services": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "created_at": "2021-08-18T17:35:52.506Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-18T17:35:52.506Z",
          "title": "new service by me"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "created_at": "2021-08-13T15:58:01.918Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-13T15:58:01.918Z",
          "title": "testing service creation at night again & again"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "created_at": "2021-09-09T12:58:05.564Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-09T13:47:37.299Z",
      "name": "Doctor Name",
      "bio": "Doctor Bio",
      "services": [
        {
          "id": 26,
          "created_at": "2021-08-13T08:47:07.941Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-13T08:47:07.941Z",
          "title": "service 26"
        },
        {
          "id": 36,
          "created_at": "2021-08-13T08:49:22.732Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-13T08:49:22.732Z",
          "title": "service 36"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "created_at": "2021-08-08T19:18:26.056Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-08T19:18:26.056Z",
          "title": "service 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 77,
          "created_at": "2021-08-13T10:12:55.529Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-13T10:12:55.529Z",
          "title": "testy 10"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

As you see, I have `Doctor` & `Service` entity that `Doctor` entity has Many-to-Many relation with service entity. Everything is ok until here.

But I wanna filter result by services ids, I mean I have an array of ids like this:

```
const servicesArray = [1, 2]
```

And I wanna filter result by services ids. I tested many ways but I didn't get my answer.

Note: This code didn't solve my problem:

```
andWhere('services.id in (:...ids)', {
  ids: servicesArray,
 })
```

And for better understanding this is what I expect:
Items that filtered by services ids (item that has services with the id of 1 and 2);

```
[
{
      "id": 3,
      "created_at": "2021-09-09T14:11:09.779Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-09-09T14:11:09.779Z",
      "name": "Test Doctor Name",
      "bio": "Test Doctor Bio",
      "services": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "created_at": "2021-08-18T17:35:52.506Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-18T17:35:52.506Z",
          "title": "new service by me"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "created_at": "2021-08-13T15:58:01.918Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-08-13T15:58:01.918Z",
          "title": "testing service creation at night again & again"
        }
      ]
    },
]
```

I also added :

```
query
  .addSelect('COUNT(services.id)', 'services_count')
  .groupBy('services.id')
  .addGroupBy('doctor.id');
```

But the problem isn't solved, because `addSelect` doesn't work with `getMany`, it works with `getRawMany`.